# Is there a tool to view named pipe security DACL?

Tags: windows, named-pipes, dacl

I tried using pipeacl and process explorer from sysinternals.

pipeacl gave me an error, and sysinternals does not seem to support security for named pipes.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that if Process Explorer doesn't support a feature, [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/)  usually does, and vice versa. Have not checked it for named pipes support but its worth a shot.